# Verifying the (real) sum of the series, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-|n|}e^{inx}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I found the  old solution of it and it says that $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-|n|}e^{inx}=\frac{13-8\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}.$$

I wondered it might be a mistake. Here's what I think the result should be
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-|n|}e^{inx}&=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left ( 2^{-n}e^{inx}+2^{-n}e^{-inx} \right )\\
&=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left ( \frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right )^{n}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left ( \frac{e^{-ix}}{2} \right )^{n}\\
&=1+\left [ \left ( 1-\frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right )^{-1}-1 \right ]+\left [ \left ( 1-\frac{e^{-ix}}{2} \right )^{-1}-1 \right ]\\
&=\left ( 1-\frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right )^{-1}+\left ( 1-\frac{e^{-ix}}{2} \right )^{-1}-1\\
&=\frac{2-\cos(x)}{\frac{5}{4}-\cos(x)}-1\\
&=\frac{-3}{4\cos(x)-5}.
\end{align}
I can't check if the result is correct in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: You are right, and the old solution is wrong.

Comment: It would appear that the author(s) had written the summation result in error. The result asked is obtained from \begin{align} 2 + \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} 2^{- |n| } \, e^{i n x} = \frac{13 - 8 \cos x}{5 - 4 \cos x} \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a double geometric series. By absolute convergence we can write it as

> $$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({e^{ix}\over 2}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({e^{-ix}\over 2}\right)^n$$

This gives

$$1+{e^{ix}/2\over 1-e^{ix}/2}+{e^{-ix}/2\over 1-e^{-ix}/2}$$

Clearing out some denominators gives

$$1+{e^{ix}\over 2-e^{ix}}+{e^{-ix}\over 2- e^{-ix}}$$

Getting a common denominator for the fractions yields

$$1+{e^{ix}(2-e^{-ix})+e^{-ix}(2-e^{ix})\over (2-e^{ix})(2-e^{-ix})}$$

$$=1+{2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})-2\over 4+-2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+1}$$

Now $\cos x={e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\over 2}$ so we see this is

$$1+{4\cos x-2\over 5-4\cos x}$$

Finally putting the $1$ into the fraction we get

> $${5-4\cos x+4\cos x-2\over 5-4\cos x}={3\over 5-4\cos x}$$

which agrees with what you put.